# c# duplicate panels dynamically

Tags: c#, dynamic, duplicates, panel

I need to dynamically duplicate a Panel with all the controls within it according to the checkboxes.
(If check-box is checked another panel appears).

Finally, when I click Calculate it's doing the same pre-defined action for each panel that created.

Picture to understand:

[image]

Can someone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Is there a reason why a UserControl won't work?

Comment: Make it a UserControl, and when a checkbox is checked, add a new user control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the controls you want into a UserControl.

When a checkbox is checked, created an instance of that control and add it.

```
MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();
myPanel.Location = new Point(25,25);
this.Controls.Add (myPanel);
```

Location is where you want it in your form.